# Can the routes /users, /users/:id, and /users/online co-exist with react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've been asked to create the following 3 routes for backwards compatibility reasons:

- `/users` lists all users
- `/users/:id` goes to a detail view of one user by id
- `/users/online` is a filtered view of `/users`, where only the online users are present.

I know that `online` will never be a valid `id`, so it will never conceptually collide with the `/users/:id` endpoint, but is react router able to handle this?

Here is what I've tried so far, which isn't working as expected:

```
<Route exact path="/users" component={UserList} />
<Route exact path="/users/:id" component={UserDetail} />
<Route exact path="/users/online/:q" component={UserList} />
```

Comment: I don't know about react-router, but maybe you want to go to `/users/online/`

Comment: @Neoares Thanks.  I added the routes I'm testing now, and that's included.  Doesn't seem to be working though, unfortunately!

Comment: "isn't working as expected" is *not* a good problem description. *what* did you expect and *in what way* were your expectations not met? Don't leave it for us to *guess* at how you tested this setup and in what ways you concluded it was not working. As a start, are *any* of the routes working? If so, which one(s)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sorry for the ambiguity.  The first 2 routes work.  The component listed gets mounted, and we're in business. The third 'online' component does work - meaning that we aren't mounting the `UserList` component by going to `localhost/users/online` or `localhost/users/online/all`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to place the `online` route before the wildcard-like parameter `:id`.
because `/:id` and `/online` are at the same level, and `:id` is defined before, when you reach `/online` it will be caught as "id".

```
<Route exact path="/users" component={UserList} />
<Route exact path="/users/online/:q" component={UserList} />
<Route exact path="/users/:id" component={UserDetail} />
```